# How to make this query simpler

Tags: sql-server, join, union

```
  SELECT IH.InvoiceNo,
    C.Name AS NameofCustomer,
    IP.Amount AS CashAmount,
    0 CreditNote,
    0 ChequeAmount,
    0 Credit,
    IP.Amount AS SalesValue 
  FROM InvoiceHeader IH
LEFT JOIN Customer C ON IH.CustomerId = C.Id
LEFT JOIN InvoiceDetail ID ON ID.InvoiceNo = IH.InvoiceNo
LEFT JOIN DistributionCenter DC ON DC.Id = ID.DistributionCenterId
LEFT JOIN InvoicePayment IP ON IP.InvoiceNo = IH.InvoiceNo
WHERE DC.Id = 1 AND IP.PaymentTypeId=1 AND IP.InvoiceDate 
BETWEEN'2018/05/01' AND '2018/06/19' AND IH.Deleted = 0 
  UNION
SELECT  IH.InvoiceNo,
     C.Name AS NameofCustomer,
     0 CashAmount,
     IP.Amount AS CreditNote,
     0 ChequeAmount,
     0 Credit,
     IP.Amount AS SalesValue 
FROM InvoiceHeader IH
LEFT JOIN Customer C ON IH.CustomerId = C.Id
LEFT JOIN InvoiceDetail ID ON ID.InvoiceNo = IH.InvoiceNo
LEFT JOIN DistributionCenter DC ON DC.Id = ID.DistributionCenterId
LEFT JOIN InvoicePayment IP ON IP.InvoiceNo = IH.InvoiceNo
WHERE DC.Id = 1 AND IP.PaymentTypeId=2 AND IP.InvoiceDate BETWEE'2018/05/01' 
AND '2018/06/19' AND IH.Deleted = 0 
 UNION
    SELECT  IH.InvoiceNo,
     C.Name AS NameofCustomer,
     0 CashAmount,
     0 CreditNote,
     IP.Amount AS ChequeAmount,
     0 Credit,
     IP.Amount AS SalesValue 
   FROM InvoiceHeader IH
   LEFT JOIN Customer C ON IH.CustomerId = C.Id
   LEFT JOIN InvoiceDetail ID ON ID.InvoiceNo = IH.InvoiceNo
   LEFT JOIN DistributionCenter DC ON DC.Id = ID.DistributionCenterId
   LEFT JOIN InvoicePayment IP ON IP.InvoiceNo = IH.InvoiceNo
   WHERE DC.Id = 1 AND IP.PaymentTypeId=3 AND IP.InvoiceDate BETWEEN 
  '2018/05/01' AND '2018/06/19' AND IH.Deleted = 0 
   UNION
 SELECT  IH.InvoiceNo,
     C.Name AS NameofCustomer,
     0 CashAmount,
     0 CreditNote,
     0 ChequeAmount,
     IP.Amount AS Credit,
     IP.Amount AS SalesValue 
 FROM InvoiceHeader IH
 LEFT JOIN Customer C ON IH.CustomerId = C.Id
 LEFT JOIN InvoiceDetail ID ON ID.InvoiceNo = IH.InvoiceNo
 LEFT JOIN DistributionCenter DC ON DC.Id = ID.DistributionCenterId
 LEFT JOIN InvoicePayment IP ON IP.InvoiceNo = IH.InvoiceNo
 WHERE DC.Id = 1 AND IP.PaymentTypeId=4 AND IP.InvoiceDate BETWEEN 
 '2018/05/01' AND '2018/06/19' AND IH.Deleted = 0 
 ORDER BY IH.InvoiceNo
```

Amount has values that paid and PaymentTypeId has the payment type. I am trying to retrieve data into 4 colomns with condition of PaymentTypeId = 1,2,3 or 4  this is the query i got. Are there any simple way to this task?

Comment: Is your current query producing the result you're looking for? If not, please describe what you're trying to get. It looks like you might be trying to build a `PIVOT`.

Comment: @SQLFox I don't know about PIVOT yet I will go through it and this query gives me the output as i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at least it seems like you can get rid of the `UNION`s. Use a `CASE ... END` to get the values for `cashamount`, `creditnote`, `chequeamount` and `credit` depending on `paymenttypeid`. Use `IN` (or multiple `OR`) to filter for `paymenttypeid` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ih.invoiceno,
       c.name nameofcustomer,
       CASE ip.pamenttypeid
         WHEN 1
           THEN ip.amount
         ELSE
           0
       END cashamount,
       CASE ip.paymenttypeid
         WHEN 2
           THEN ip.amount
         ELSE
           0
       END creditnote,
       CASE ip.paymenttypeid
         WHEN 3
           THEN ip.amount
         ELSE
           0
       END chequeamount,
       CASE ip.paymenttypeid
         WHEN 4
           THEN ip.amount
         ELSE
           0
       END credit,
       ip.amount salesvalue 
       FROM invoiceheader ih
            LEFT JOIN customer c
                      ON c.id = ih.customerid
            LEFT JOIN invoicedetail id
                      ON id.invoiceno = ih.invoiceno
            LEFT JOIN distributioncenter dc
                      ON dc.id = id.distributioncenterid
            LEFT JOIN invoicepayment ip
                      ON ip.invoiceno = ih.invoiceno
       WHERE dc.id = 1
             AND ip.paymenttypeid IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
             AND ip.invoicedate BETWEEN '2018/05/01'
                                        AND '2018/06/19'
             AND ih.deleted = 0;
```

Note, that `UNION` eliminates duplicates. So I added `DISTINCT` to have duplicates eliminated in this version too. Remove it, if this side effect of `UNION` wasn't actually wanted or if there cannot be any duplicates (I don't have the complete picture of your schema to judge that.).

But, it's only a shorter query text. Depending on the existing indexes, your first approach might execute faster. Check the execution plans, when in doubt.

Comment: Your last paragraph is probably the most important here. It's critical to remember that with SQL, "simple" or "concise" code *doesn't* always translate to better performance - sometimes the opposite. One of the goals in writing a query (after getting the correct results) is to give the database engine as much information as possible so that it can make the best available optimization decision. Sometimes that "looks like" more work (because it's longer, uses additional language features, etc.) but ultimately yields a better-performing query.

Comment: This query gives me the out put but it takes 9 seconds , mine is 1 second and thank you for explaining the query you post @sticky bit

Comment: @alroc thank you for explaining about simple and optimization.